# Error when creating bean in configuration class, SpringBoot & JavaFX?

Tags: java, spring-boot, javafx

My project is using SpringBoot integrated with JavaFX. I follow the template from https://github.com/RamAlapure/JavaFXSpringBootApp and change something.

Application class:

```
public class UIApplication extends Application {
    protected ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
    protected StageManager stageManager;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = springBootApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stageManager = springContext.getBean(StageManager.class, stage); // I debugged and it seems there's no problem from javaFX here 
        displayInitialScene();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        springContext.close();
    }

    /**
     * Useful to override this method by sub-classes wishing to change the first
     * Scene to be displayed on startup. Example: Functional tests on main
     * window.
     */
    protected void displayInitialScene() {
        stageManager.switchScene("/fxml/login-register.fxml", "Login-Register");
    }


    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springBootApplicationContext() {
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(UIApplication.class);
        String[] args = getParameters().getRaw().stream().toArray(String[]::new);
        return builder.run(args);
    }

}
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class AppJavaConfig {
    @Autowired 
    SpringFXMLLoader springFXMLLoader;
    ...
    @Bean
    @Lazy(value = true) //Stage only created after Spring context bootstap
    public StageManager stageManager(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        return new StageManager(springFXMLLoader, stage); // this code may not work, bean not created, but i don't know how to debug into this line.
    }
}
```

I got this error:

```
2022-06-19 01:25:58.065  INFO 18484 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application using Java 11.0.11 on Tungdz with PID 18484 (started by Tunght in C:\Users\DaiPhongPC\OneDrive\Desktop\network-programming-gr10)
2022-06-19 01:25:58.068  INFO 18484 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-06-19 01:25:58.184  INFO 18484 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 0.921 seconds (JVM running for 3.754)
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.gr10.clientapp.fx.config.StageManager' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1178)
    at com.gr10.clientapp.UIApplication.start(UIApplication.java:20)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run$$$capture(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56360', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I comment some debug result in the code above.

Summary: I think Spring could not create bean so I can not get it from ApplicationContext.

Could you guys help me to let this sh*t run please :((

Comment: whats your folder structure like, also the code you are referencing is spring `1.5.2.RELEASE` which was release over 5 years ago (2017) current version of spring is `2.7.0` so please dont use outdated things

Comment: UIApplication in com.gr10.clientapp (base package). and AppJavaConfig in package fx.config (below base package). I use the current vers of Spring, and don't use the whole GitHub project, just took 3 class of him. @Toerktumlare

Comment: all annotated classes must be below in the directory/package tree of the main class for the scan to work and your explanation is unclear on this point. Run your application in debug mode and read the logs to see what is loaded or not. You should actually debug your application before asking on stacck overflow

Comment: Thank you @Toerktumlare. I have some experience with spring boot so I think my package structure is not the problem. First time I use SpringBoot with JavaFX and I not so clear with JavaFX. I tried to debug and commented some debug result above (method start of JavaFX is correct, class name and param are ok, it just can not get bean from IoC container). But I don’t have experience debugging inside the framework (configuration class, how spring init beans), so I not sure whether spring create bean successfully !_!

Comment: I will write my question more details. I need to go to sleep, 3 a.m now :((

Comment: There are [543](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bspring%5D+NoSuchBeanDefinitionException) questions on StackOverflow about NoSuchBeanDefinitionException. Your answer is probably in one of them.  This seems a generic Spring config error and nothing JavaFX specific.

Comment: The template you adapted targets Java 8, which is obsolete.  I don’t recommend following it, especially as you are using Java 11 and JavaFX was included in Java 8, but not Java 11, so its setup between the two is very different.